# How can I install bundler for a specific ruby version?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails app and when I try to run rake db:migrate I get this error:

---

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
```

---

I'm using **rbenv** and **ruby version 2.5.1** in a mac with OS Mojave 10.14.4

I've tried installing bundle with
    **gem install bundle**
And it installs it successfully, but then when I try to run **bundle install**, I get the message:

---

```
rbenv: bundle: command not found 

The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions: 

2.6.2
```

---

I've tried making sure I'm currently using ruby 2.5.1 checking with ruby -v and also creating an environment variable to define what version to use with:

---

```
 export RBENV_VERSION=2.5.1
```

---

Also when I type **rbenv versions** I get:

---

```
system
* 2.5.1
2.6.2
```

---

Showing I'm using 2.5.1

I suspect there might be two 2.5.1 versions of ruby installed in different places, maybe one with rvm (which I already uninstalled with **rmv implode** but didn't know I had). Or I might be missing some rbenv configurations.

But nothing seems to work, apparently **gem install** installs bundle for ruby 2.6.2 only. How can I fix this?

I'm not 100% sure of everything I'm doing, so far I've just followed online tutorials, so please help me understand what's going on and what to do.